# I can get Lat and Long but I can't access the GPS altitude info in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, gps, cllocation

I've been trying to get the altitude from a CLLocation that i get from from the CoreLocation framework using the following code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

/*
Note: This needs to be added to the info.plist file for this to work:

<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key> <string>Your message</string> <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key> <string>Your message</string> <key>NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your message</string>
*/

@IBOutlet weak var gpsResult: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var altitudeLabel: UILabel!


var manager:CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

}

func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations myLocations:CLLocation) {
    if manager != nil {
        var alt:CLLocationDistance = myLocations.altitude

        gpsResult.text = "locations = \(myLocations)"
        altitudeLabel.text = "GPS Altitude: \(Double(alt))"
        // manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
}
```

So if I only request the location I'm able to get the gpsResult.text value and it works correctly but when I try to access the altitude I get an error:

```
 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM altitude]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17404dcb0'
```

The thing is as per [apple's reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/index.html) that selector should exist.
I went through the posts here and the net and I tried their code but all of them failed.

Does anyone haven an idea what's goig on?

Thanks.

Comment: You are running it against an array. MyLocations is an array not a CLLocation.

Comment: @Fogmeister is correct. The didUpdateLocations delegate method passes an array of CLLocation objects (so myLocations parameter type should be `[AnyObject]!`).  By "declaring" it as a single CLLocation, it does not automatically turn into a single CLLocation -- it is still an array of CLLocations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Apple's documentation [CLLocationManagerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/CLLocationManagerDelegate) the `locations` parameter of `didUpdateLocations` gives:

> An array of CLLocation objects containing the location data. This
>   array always contains at least one object representing the current
>   location. If updates were deferred or if multiple locations arrived
>   before they could be delivered, the array may contain additional
>   entries. The objects in the array are organized in the order in which
>   they occurred. Therefore, the most recent location update is at the
>   end of the array.

So you can access the most recent location via the last element in the array:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    let location = locations.last

    gpsResult.text = "locations = \(location)"
    altitudeLabel.text = "GPS Altitude: \(location.altitude)"
    // manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Comment: thanks @zisoft that worked. I did get a warning because of the AnyObjet being assigned to a constant so I modified it to this:

    func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations myLocations: [CLLocation!]) {
        if manager != nil {
            let alt = myLocations.last
            
            gpsResult.text = "locations = \(myLocations)"
            altitudeLabel.text = "GPS Altitude: \(alt?.altitude)"
            // manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }

also I get a long string as a result "Optional(714.56465456464)"